# How to compile two lists of closing prices from websocket client?

Tags: python, json, list, websocket, ta-lib

I am running a standard buy/sell trader using `websocket` and `talib`. With the socket, I am able to get 2 messages through with different time intervals (1min and 3min). I am getting ETHUDS data only but with two different time intervals using this socket:

```
TRADE_SYMBOOL = 'ethusdt'
INTERVAL = '1m'
INTERVAL_2 = '3m'
SOCKET = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{TRADE_SYMBOOL}@kline_{INTERVAL}/{TRADE_SYMBOOL}@kline_{INTERVAL_2}'
```

This gives me a `json.loads(message)` of:

```
{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1646017123875, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 'k': {'t': 1646017080000, 'T': 1646017139999, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 'i': '1m', 'f': 769965188, 'L': 769965629, 'o': '2605.00000000', 'c': '2605.88000000', 'h': '2606.98000000', 'l': '2603.21000000', 'v': '191.57300000', 'n': 442, 'x': False, 'q': '499047.95132700', 'V': '78.57690000', 'Q': '204678.10094600', 'B': '0'}}
{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1646017123875, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 'k': {'t': 1646017020000, 'T': 1646017199999, 's': 'ETHUSDT', 'i': '3m', 'f': 769964266, 'L': 769965629, 'o': '2599.08000000', 'c': '2605.88000000', 'h': '2606.98000000', 'l': '2595.10000000', 'v': '922.85610000', 'n': 1364, 'x': False, 'q': '2399363.68094500', 'V': '356.83860000', 'Q': '928388.14101500', 'B': '0'}}
```

If you scroll across a bit, the `'i'` tick is showing `1m` in one and `3m` in the next.

I am then extracting the close `'c'` from the line and compiling a list of closes.

What I want to be able to do is make a list of closes from the `1m` list and then a separate list from the `3m` list.

```
closes = []
def on_message(ws, message):
    global in_position  
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    candle = json_message['k']  
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']
    if is_candle_closed:  # this only returns True at the end of each candle close (1minute)
        closes.append(float(close))
```

This is what I was using when I was only using `1m` intervals, but now I don't know how to sort the 2 json loads that are coming in with each message. How can I differentiate between the two pieces of json data so I can store their closing prices accordingly?

I need to be able to store the closing prices from the `1m` and `3m` candles as separate lists.

How can I list closes into two separate list eg. `closes_1m` and `closes_3m` please?

I would like list `closes_1m` to contain the price of the close after every 1 minute.

I would like list `closes_3m` to contain the price of the close after every 3 minutes.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add your desired output also !

Comment: I have edited and hope it is more clear, thank you for the input.

Comment: Do you want to store all close prices based on 'i' which is '1m' or '3m' ? In other word: for every api calls to binance you want store this two close prices ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to separate them with a simple `if` statement.

```
closes_1m = []
closes_3m = []    
def on_message(ws, message):
        json_message = json.loads(message)
        candle = json_message['k']
        is_candle_closed = candle['x']
        close = candle['c']
        close_time = int(candle['T']) / 1000
        interval = candle['i']
        if interval == '1m' and is_candle_closed:  # this only runs at the end of each candle close (1minute)
            closes_1m.append(float(close))
        if interval == '3m' and is_candle_closed:  # this only runs at the end of each candle close (3minute)
        closes_3m.append(float(close))
```

So every 1 minute I appended a closing price to `closes_1m` and every 3 minutes I appended the closing price data to `closes_3m`.